# User will redirect to page as per thier role after login in apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-19.1

my apex application has functionality that all users and admin are redirected to home page after login and for that i set user interface home url to f?p= &APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.

Now I wanted the functionality where the users will redirect to page number 2 and admin will redirect to home page (1). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have everyone go to page 2 as the default, but have a branch on page 2 in your pre-header which redirects to page 1. Then for the server-side condition for that branch, add some logic (presumably PLSQL) to see if you are the admin.